# Memtable type and size allocation

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

In Cassandra 3.11.2, there are 3 choices for the type of Memtable allocation and as per my understanding, if I want to keep Memtables on JVM heap I can use **`heap_buffers`** and if I want to store Memtables outside of JVM heap then I've got 2 options **`offheap_buffers`** and **`offheap_objects`**.

What exactly is the difference between the 2 choices given for off-heap allocation?

Also, the permitted memory space to be used for Memtables can be set at 2 places in the YAML file, i.e. **`memtable_heap_space_in_mb`** and **`memtable_offheap_space_in_mb`**.

Do I need to configure some space in both heap and offheap, irrespective of the Memtable allocation type or do I need to set only one of them based on my Memtable allocation type i.e. **`memtable_heap_space_in_mb`** when using **`heap buffers`** and **`memtable_offheap_space_in_mb`** only when using either of the other 2 offheap options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **heap_buffers** (which is the default) allocates memtables on the heap using Java NIO.
- **offheap_buffers** allocates a portion of each memtable both on and off the heap using the same Java NIO.
- **offheap_objects** uses native memory directly, so Cassandra will manage by itself the memtable memory (both allocation and garbage collection). This feature it's not very well documented so maybe it's better not to use it.

For both **memtable_heap_space_in_mb** and **memtable_offheap_space_in_mb** I think it's best to stick with the default values. For each, the default is 1/4 of the total heap size. But if you plan to change something, probably it's better to make really small changes, since it will reduce the amount of memory that Cassandra can use.

Comment: So, 'memtable_heap_space_in_mb' , is of no use if we are using memtable allocation type as 'offheap_objects'? It can be commented out from the YAML then in this case?

Comment: No matter which variant of the offheap setting you use, @VishalSharma you will still use the memtable heap space.  Depending on what type of columns you have in your tables, you may need more or less of the offheap and heap side.  Check your server logs to see which memtable region is usually the limiting factor that triggers a flush, and consider balancing the two so that both are about equally likely to trigger a flush.